# [body onload]FadeIn a div after a Set of time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been looking about how to fade a div after a set of time with jQuery.

I tried

```
$(test).fadeIn("slow").delay(2000)
```

But I think I am missing something on the code?

Comment: What does test stand for? Name, variable, id, class etc? Maybe you should use: $('#test')

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
setTimeout(function(){$('#test').fadeIn('slow');}, 2000);
```

Comment: Should I display:none; the div?

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(myFunc, 2000);
function myFunc(){
$(test).fadeIn('slow');
}
```

Comment: You can pass an variable that contains a string, be it an ID, class, or even a block of HTML into the jQuery selector.

Comment: yes it is correct. I did not assume that you create a test variable

Answer (score 0):

you need to delay first, and then attemot the fade in

```
$(test).delay(2000).fadeIn("slow");
```

Answer (score 0):

turn it around:

```
<div id="test" style="display:none">Hello!</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

   $("#test").delay(2000).fadeIn("slow")
});
</script>
```